# Buildroot - Updating trust store using update-ca-certificates

Tags: embedded-linux, buildroot, truststore

I am working on Buildroot to build custom Linux image. I am trying to add a custom CA to the trust store. I have copied the CA file to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` in the rootfs_overlay and also has a `.crt` extension. Now after executing `make` the CA is not added to the trust store in `/etc/ssl/certs/` in the target. Anyways it's installed only in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` in the target. I thought the `update-ca-certificates` will add this during image build.
Can anyone please let me know what is missing here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

For anyone finding this on StackOverflow, this topic has been discussed on the Buildroot mailing list at https://lore.kernel.org/buildroot/CADYjeStG8bZEBprwqez+_3+n-HZ5pG9p8mBySxV+4FU7GM0r3g@mail.gmail.com/.